# How to format csv to html table rows and columns using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

How can I take the following chunk of csv data and convert it to tr's and td's, using javascript?

```
Jess,Female,04/26/1990,North Central College,Aix,Spring 2012,WebApp,
MC,Female,04/27/1991,Carnegie Mellon University,Aix,Spring 2012,WebApp,
Sharon,Female,04/03/1967,Hobart and William Smith Colleges,Aix,Spring 2012,WebApp,
Nancy,Female,08/15/1989,The New School,Aix,Spring 2011,WebApp,
Jacqueline,Female,03/18/1991,University of South Carolina,Aix,Spring 2011,WebApp,
Sydney,Female,12/11/1990,University of Vermont,Aix,Spring 2011,WebApp,
Kelsey,Female,12/08/1989,University of Vermont,Aix,Spring 2011,WebApp,
Oktavia,Female,11/05/1990,SUNY - Albany,Aix,Spring 2011,WebApp,
Courtney,Female,12/02/1988,Ithaca College,Aix,Spring 2009,WebApp,
Nike,Female,24.2.1989,Appleby College,Aix,Spring 2008,WebApp,
Linda,Female,8/26/1964,Kalamazoo College,Aix,Spring 2009,WebApp,
Allison,Female,12/15/1976,University of San Diego,Aix,Spring 2009,WebApp,
Carmen,Female,02/07/1988,Carnegie Mellon University,Aix,Spring 2008,WebApp,
Nora,Female,10/23/88,Eastern Washington University,Aix,Spring 2009,WebApp,
Jennifer,Female,10/27/79,University of Kansas,Aix,Spring 2009,WebApp,
```

**Desired Table Format** for each of the lines in the csv data.

```
<tr><td>Jess</td> <td>Female<td><td>04/26/1990</td><td>North Central College</td><td>Aix</td><td>Spring 2012</td><td>WebApp</td></tr>
```

Comment: In JavaScript? Is that CSV retrieved via Ajax, or...?

Comment: Sorry, Yes JavaScript and the csv data is retrieved via Ajax. Just updated the question.

Comment: @CarlWeis Yes, but how are you getting the data in to Javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have that CSV data in a variable (whether retrieved via Ajax or whatever) then you can use the [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get an array of lines and split each line on commas:

```
var data = // your data
var lines = data.split("\n"),
    output = [],
    i;
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    output.push("<tr><td>"
                + lines[i].slice(0,-1).split(",").join("</td><td>")
                + "</td></tr>");
output = "<table>" + output.join("") + "</table>";
```

(The string [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is to ignore the trailing commas on each line.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/frvQ2/

Comment: How would I do the reverse. Take the html just the tr's and td's and convert those to the csv format? Because it's not working with some of the data I have.

Comment: `yourHTML.replace(/<tr>|<td>/g,"").replace(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/<\/td>/g,",").replace(/<\/tr>/g,"\n")` would turn a string of tr and td elements back into CSV. Or adapt the code in my answer to split on the tags and join on commas and newline characters...

Comment: keep getting object has no method push

Comment: @josh - `.push()` is an array method. Is your object an array as shown in my answer?

Comment: @nnn yup totally aware its a array prototype method, for some reason when i remove the brackets i added for the for statement it doesn't throw that error

Comment: Also another note you don't need to add i to the vars you can include it in the for loop like this for(var i = 0;i<lines.length;i++) no need to cache it unless your using outside of the closure

Comment: @josh - I'm not sure what you mean by "cache it" - the `i` variable the way I did it has exactly the same scope as the way you showed in your comment (JS doesn't have block scope for variables declared with `var`, only function scope, so your change would have no effect on execution).

Comment: @nnnnnn I just meant by keeping it around in the scope when you only need it for the for loop. guess you're right just did a performance test, for some reason i thought it was better, guess it just lowers the variable scope lookup since their are less variables to filter but it really makes no difference

Comment: @josh - it's the _same scope_ either way. Declaring it in the loop does _not_ limit the scope to the loop. (It would in some other languages but not in Javascript.)

Comment: If you don't have trailing commas after each line, remove `.slice(0,-1)`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var data = //your data

data = "<table><tr>" + 
  data.replace(/,\n/g,"<tr>")
      .replace(/,/g, "<td>")
      .replace(/<tr>$/,"") +
  "</table>";
```

Comment: This does not include proper end tags. For example `</tr>`

Comment: The end tags are optional for TR and TD.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5